# Some objects change position when becoming children of bones

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

I created shoulder plates for my armor in Blender and tried to add a Child Of constraint to it and set it to be a child of a bone in another object's rig (character's rig).

This is where the object is in relation to my character:

[image: Shoulder plate]

Having it selected I add a "Child Of" constraint to the plate:

[image]

Then I select the type of object I want to constraint it to with the picker tool (the bone that is located just under the plate, in my character's upper arm):

[image]

[image]

Then I type in the name of the bone in constraint settings:

[image]

As soon as I do that the object is much smaller and far from its previous position:

[image]

It comes back when I disable the position, rotation and scale relations, but if I do that then any movement of the bone won't affect the object, so it's going to be useless for rigging.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: check the scale on your object, and on that bone.

Comment: also clear all data on the bone (rot loc scale)

Comment: try setting the inverse, see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28859/5113

Comment: @Chebhou thank you, it works. You can post your comment as an answer and I will select it as the correct one